# Spring Cloud Stream - Dynamic Exchanges and Routing key by producer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

In Spring cloud stream producer, when using dynamic bound destinations (exchanges) using BinderAwareChannelResolver, is it possible to specify dynamic routing keys?

Comment: Looks like this GH issue is similar to what you are asking: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1009
See if the suggestions made there are applicable in your case.

Comment: I see this point in the link provided. "You can programmatically declare queues and bindings using the AmqpAdmin bean after you have resolved the destination and before sending messages." How can we do this. Is there any sample i can refer to, I am not sure how to link below two?
->resolver.resolveDestination(target).send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(body,
    new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))), 10000L);
->Binding b = new Binding("messageChannel", DestinationType.QUEUE, "messageChannel", "test", null);
      amqpAdmin.declareBinding(b);

Comment: Here is an example of how to use [dynamic sources](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/dynamic-source)